# SQL Server Data Tools: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard Cut Off

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

The interactive text box when selecting "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" gets cutoff so I cannot input my password:

[image]

If I try to select a different data source and navigate back, even more gets cut off:

[image]

If I navigate back again, more is cut off:

[image]

Finally, all preferences is cut off:

[image]

I am on the following version:

[image]

I don't have access to privileges to update Server Data Tools, so if there's a fix or workaround within my version that would be great.

I tried restarting the application and restarting the computer. The error persists. I was expecting to see "password" and be able to input that password.

Comment: btw, _SQL Server Native Client 11.0_ is obsolete and was removed from SQL Server 2022-era tooling. Is there a reason you can't use the more up-to-date OLEDB client?

Comment: Also, as these are all just high-dpi bugs, you could just use SSMS with high-dpi disabled

Comment: I just realised you're trying to use SSIS via SSDT instead of via SSMS - why are you doing it this way?

Comment: I am doing what I was instructed by my professor to do.

Comment: Update: maximizing the window fixed the error

Comment: Aside... SQL Server Native Client 11.0 is well and truly deprecated. It hasn't received any feature updates since SQL Server 2012, is not compatible with modern TDS protocol features, and Microsoft **finally** shopped distributing it once SQL Server 2022 was released. Consider switching to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (or later) for new application development and migrate existing applications as well.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I will say there is at least _one_ upside to SNAC 11.0 (which is why I kept on using it for over 10 years): when in the Import/Export Wizard the SNAC 11 client (seems to) remember credentials and database names which means I can quickly navigate through the Import/Export Wizard without re-entering DB credentials, but all the other Data Source selections for Import/Export have a poorer overall UX. I'm unsure if my experience is a common one or not, though...

Comment: @Dai it's your choice, as always. People still drop questions here about SQL Server 2005, too. :)